# User generated filter and content, how could I write this better

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am writing a (multi)filter that is created when the user enters in the data through wordpress. There can be anywhere between 2 - 10 filters so I need this to be as dynamic as possible. My first approach was to write out a boolean for each possible filter being created and check if it is there or not. Inside the boolean is a click function that checks if the data==="yes" and then add a active class to the item. I rewrote it in a do while, but am not sure if this is the best approach or if they are both bad.

**I am not looking for a complete answer or working example**, but rather if my way makes sense? If so why? if not, why not? And an explanation of how I could possible improve it or think of it in a different way.

**manually Check**

```
var mem = $(".member");

var filter1 = $(".filter-1");
var filter2 = $(".filter-2");
var filter3 = $(".filter-3");

var memCom1 = $(".member").data("com-1");
var memCom2 = $(".member").data("com-2");
var memCom3 = $(".member").data("com-3");

//  DO THIS FOR ALL POSSIBLE

if (memCom1.length > 0 || filter1.length > 0) {
    filter1.click(function() {
        var com1 = $(this).data("com-1");
        if(com1 === "yes") {
            $(this).addClass(active);
        }
    });
}

if (memCom2.length > 0 || filter2.length > 0) {
    filter2.click(function() {
        var com2 = $(this).data("com-2");
        if(com2 === "yes") {
            $(this).addClass(active);
        }
    });
}

if (memCom3.length > 0 || filter3.length > 0) {
    filter3.click(function() {
        var com3 = $(this).data("com-3");
        if(com3 === "yes") {
            $(this).addClass(active);
        }
    });
}

// would go up to 10
```

**DO WHILE**

```
var mem = $(".member");
var active = "is-active"

do {
    var i = 1;
    if ( $(".member").data("com-"+i).length > 0 || $(".filter"+i).length > 0 ) {
        $(".filter-"+i).click(function() {
            if( $(this).data("com-"+i) === "yes" ) {
                $(this).addClass(active);
            }
        });
    }
  i++;
}

while (i <= mem.length);
```

Comment: Try this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! Just did that.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, using $.each() instead of do-while will have cleaner code. Also, I think having the same attribute "com" would simplify than "com-#". For problem like these, its helpful to post a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing more details about you app, your second approach using do-while looks preferable because it uses less code and is easier to maintain/extend. However, it looks like you can reuse 'mem' variable in your if condition.